# When using UIActionSheet on the iPad with more than a few buttons, the height often is incorrect, resulting in clipped buttons

Tags: ios, ipad, uiactionsheet, popover

So I've tried searching just about everywhere with the terms that makes sense to me, but I'm coming up empty. Surely this problem doesn't affect only me?

Assuming the following code (on the iPad):

```
    UIActionSheet *theActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                                     initWithTitle: nil
                                          delegate: self 
                                 cancelButtonTitle: nil 
                            destructiveButtonTitle: nil 
                                 otherButtonTitles: nil ];
    [theActionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 1"];
    ... (repeat a goodly number of times, say, 13 more times)
    [theActionSheet showFromRect:theRect inView:self.tableView animated:YES]
```

Now, depending on where I show the sheet from, I may end up with a fully-formed sheet (that is, all buttons showing), or I may end up with the bottom button being partially (or fully) clipped. For example:

[image: Clipped Popover]

I understand that the size of this popover is running into the bounds of the screen, but it would seem that the iPad should transition to a scrollable list of items. *Note:* When adding a title, this is exactly what happens. That said, having a title only seems to exacerbate the clipping issues.

Technically the number of items presented is extreme - the average user would not see all of these items at once. However, in the case that all the items are applicable, I would prefer not to have clipped buttons.

As a side note, I've seen this occur every once in a while other apps (wish I could remember which one atm, but can't), so I'm thinking this isn't just my code, but something wrong with the way the action sheet and it's popover interact when displaying on an iPad where the border may come into play.

Any thoughts on how to fix, mitigate, get around, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A redesign should be priority number one.  This can clearly be moved into a more efficient controller (a popover with a UIPageControl), or split into multiple sheets with a UIMenuController.  If you do want the scrolling, may I recommend an indicator in the title about the need to scroll.  (PS, I would asked this on [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), but that's just me).

Comment: With all due respect, I'm not sure either option with a redesign would be at all helpful here. This popover appears on a long-press (akin to selection), and is intended to provide quick access to the various items. I don't want the end-user to have to swipe the page controller three or four times just to get to the "Explain" button.

Nor do I see how a UIMenuController is going to help: all it's going to do is take what is vertical and compress it horizontally, and require multiple taps to see the additional options. Again, something I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: THen what about the way iBooks does annotations (UIMenuController where each option is a broad category that leads to a smaller, more efficient individual action sheet).

Comment: Okay, that works to a degree. It makes highlighting/searching a bit more tedious (two clicks), and on the iPhone, it requires several nexts/prevs to get to the one you want, but for now it's the best option. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: My (albeit evil) brain has thought of a way to capitalize on this!  What if you limited their options and required a purchase (like the way paper makes you buy more complicated brushes and stencils)?